# Browser detection versus capability detection for IE 6 select / z-index bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I have a written a jquery plug-in which pops-up a div section on hover over an element, and I need to deal with the "select z-index" bug in IE6 (http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx). So, if running in IE6, my code needs to hide some select boxes on the page, when the pop-up div is visible.

My question is: In trying to follow best practices, I would like to avoid detecting the actual browser version and instead do a 'feature-test", to determine whether I am in an affected browser. ([http://ejohn.org/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries](http://ejohn.org/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries/)). Is there any way to do this? Or should I just treat this as a special case, detect the browser and handle IE6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [bgiframe plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) to fix the bug without having to hide the select boxes on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet all the time. It's cool because it checks only for IE6. But be aware that if you using any code compression tools that removes HTML comments this won't work.

```
<!-- THESE LINES ARE NOT NORMAL HTML COMMENTS! They are instructions that only IE6 can understand. -->
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // redirect to the Default error page passing a custom error code.
        window.location = '/your/redirect/page';
    </script>
```

Cheers.